# Getting wrong value for .clientHeight

Tags: javascript, html, css

There are quite a few posts here on this but none of the suggested ideas worked for me. I just am trying to get the correct height of a flex-element `div` after page rendering. Getting the `div` by `let div = document.querySelector("#cbody");` gives me

```
div#cbody.card-body
​
accessKey: ""
​
accessKeyLabel: ""
​
align: ""
​
assignedSlot: null
​
attributes: NamedNodeMap [ class="card-body", id="cbody" ]
​
baseURI: "http://matpro/toolplan"
​
childElementCount: 2
​
childNodes: NodeList(5) [ #text, div.toolbar, #text
, … ]
​
children: HTMLCollection { 0: div.toolbar, 1: div#calendar.fc.fc-media-screen.fc-direction-ltr.fc-theme-standard.fc-liquid-hack
, length: 2, … }
​
classList: DOMTokenList [ "card-body" ]
​
className: "card-body"
​
clientHeight: 1201
​
clientLeft: 1
​
clientTop: 1
​
clientWidth: 1221
​
contentEditable: "inherit"
​
dataset: DOMStringMap(0)
​
dir: ""
​
draggable: false
​
firstChild: #text "  
            "​
firstElementChild: <div class="toolbar" style="border:0px solid coral;">
​
hidden: false
​
id: "cbody"
​
innerHTML: "  \n            <div class=\"toolbar\" style=\"border:0px solid coral;\"></div>\n            <div id=\"calendar\" style=\"border:3px solid red;\" class=\"fc fc-media-screen fc-direction-ltr fc-theme-standard fc-liquid-hack\"><div class=\"fc-header-toolbar fc-toolbar fc-toolbar-ltr\"><div class=\"fc-toolbar-chunk\"><h2 class=\"fc-toolbar-title\">08.02.2021 – 04.04.2021</h2></div><div class=\"fc-toolbar-chunk\"><div class=\"fc-button-group\"><button class=\"fc-week-button fc-button fc-button-primary\" type=\"button\">Woche</button><button class=\"fc-month-button fc-button fc-button-primary fc-button-active\" type=\"button\">2 Monate</button></div></div><div class=\"fc-toolbar-chunk\"><button class=\"fc-cToday-button fc-button fc-button-primary\" type=\"button\">Heute</button><div class=\"fc-button-group\"><button class=\"fc-prevMonth-button fc-button fc-button-primary\" type=\"button\">&lt;&lt;</button><button class=\"fc-prevWeek-button fc-button fc-button-primary\" type=\"button\">&lt;</button><button class=\"fc-nextWeek-button fc-b…"
​
innerText: "08.02.2021 – 04.04.2021\nWoche\n2 Monate\nHeute\n<<\n<\n>\n>>\nRessource\nsort_by_alpha\n\t\t\nFebruar 2021\n\t\nMärz 2021\n\t\nApril 2021\n\n\n6\n\t\n7\n\t\n8\n\t\n9\n\t\n10\n\t\n11\n\t\n12\n\t\n13\n\n\nMo., 08.\n\t\nDi., 09.\n\t\nMi., 10.\n\t\nDo., 11.\n\t\nFr., 12.\n\t\nSa., 13.\n\t\nSo., 14.\n\t\nMo., 15.\n\t\nDi., 16.\n\t\nMi., 17.\n\t\nDo., 18.\n\t\nFr., 19.\n\t\nSa., 20.\n\t\nSo., 21.\n\t\nMo., 22.\n\t\nDi., 23.\n\t\nMi., 24.\n\t\nDo., 25.\n\t\nFr., 26.\n\t\nSa., 27.\n\t\nSo., 28.\n\t\nMo., 01.\n\t\nDi., 02.\n\t\nMi., 03.\n\t\nDo., 04.\n\t\nFr., 05.\n\t\nSa., 06.\n\t\nSo., 07.\n\t\nMo., 08.\n\t\nDi., 09.\n\t\nMi., 10.\n\t\nDo., 11.\n\t\nFr., 12.\n\t\nSa., 13.\n\t\nSo., 14.\n\t\nMo., 15.\n\t\nDi., 16.\n\t\nMi., 17.\n\t\nDo., 18.\n\t\nFr., 19.\n\t\nSa., 20.\n\t\nSo., 21.\n\t\nMo., 22.\n\t\nDi., 23.\n\t\nMi., 24.\n\t\nDo., 25.\n\t\nFr., 26.\n\t\nSa., 27.\n\t\nSo., 28.\n\t\nMo., 29.\n\t\nDi., 30.\n\t\nMi., 31.\n\t\nDo., 01.\n\t\nFr., 02.\n\t\nSa., 03.\n\t\nSo., 04.\n\n\nAimo-Clemens Leffers (0551)\nedit\n\n\nAlex Rabe (0724)\nedit\n\n\nAlfred Winter (0583)\nedit\n\n\nAljoscha Raschke (0874)\nedit\n\n\nAndre Elberling (0587)\nedit\n\n\nAndre Michels (0714)\nedit\n\n\nAndreas Milczewski (0575)\nedit\n\n\nAnhänger (BRA-AW 429)\nedit\n\n\nAnhänger (FRI-LA 103)\nedit\n\n\nAnhänger (FRI-LA 51)\nedit\n\n\nAnhänger (FRI-LA 80)\nedit\n\n\nAstra (FRI-LA 144)\nedit\n\n\nBaggeranhänger (FRI-LA 50)\nedit\n\n\nBastian Müller (0510)\nedit\n\n\nBenjamin Umbach (0578)\nedit\n\n\nBennet Dreemann (0876)\nedit\n\n\nBennet Visser (0911)\nedit\n\n\nCaddy (BRA-SE 103)\nedit\n\n\nCaddy (FRI-LA 20)\nedit\n\n\nCorinna Wessels (0415)\nedit\n\n\nDaniel Powollik (0593)\nedit\n\n\nHeiko Wessels (0679)\nedit\n\n\nMustermann (5559)\nedit\n\n\nTestRessource (1234)\nedit\n\t\t\n\t\n\t\n\t\n\t\n\t\n\t\n\t\n\t\n\t\n\t\n\t\n\t\n\t\n\t\n\t\n\t\n\t\n\t\n\t\n\t\n\t\n\t\n\t\n\t\n\t\n\t\n\t\n\t\n\t\n\t\n\t\n\t\n\t\n\t\n\t\n\t\n\t\n\t\n\t\n\t\n\t\n\t\n\t\n\t\n\t\n\t\n\t\n\t\n\t\n\t\n\t\n\t\n\t\n\t\n\t\nKarfreitag\nRosenmontag\nFastnacht\nAschermittwoch\nPalmsonntag\nGründonnerstag\nOstersonntag\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n"
​
isConnected: true
​
isContentEditable: false
​
lang: ""
​
lastChild: #text "
          "​
lastElementChild: <div id="calendar" class="fc fc-media-screen fc-di…standard fc-liquid-hack" style="border:3px solid red;">
​
localName: "div"
​
namespaceURI: "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
​
nextElementSibling: null
​
nextSibling: #text "
        "
​
nodeName: "DIV"
​
nodeType: 1
​
nodeValue: null
​
nonce: ""
​
offsetHeight: 1203
​
offsetLeft: 0
​
offsetParent: <div class="card" style="border:0px solid coral;padding-bottom:5px;">
​
offsetTop: 47
​
offsetWidth: 1223
​
onabort: null
​
onanimationcancel: null
​
onanimationend: null
​
onanimationiteration: null
​
onanimationstart: null
​
onauxclick: null
​
onblur: null
​
oncanplay: null
​
oncanplaythrough: null
​
onchange: null
​
onclick: null
​
onclose: null
​
oncontextmenu: null
​
oncopy: null
​
oncuechange: null
​
oncut: null
​
ondblclick: null
​
ondrag: null
​
ondragend: null
​
ondragenter: null
​
ondragexit: null
​
ondragleave: null
​
ondragover: null
​
ondragstart: null
​
ondrop: null
​
ondurationchange: null
​
onemptied: null
​
onended: null
​
onerror: null
​
onfocus: null
​
onformdata: null
​
onfullscreenchange: null
​
onfullscreenerror: null
​
ongotpointercapture: null
​
oninput: null
​
oninvalid: null
​
onkeydown: null
​
onkeypress: null
​
onkeyup: null
​
onload: null
​
onloadeddata: null
​
onloadedmetadata: null
​
onloadend: null
​
onloadstart: null
​
onlostpointercapture: null
​
onmousedown: null
​
onmouseenter: null
​
onmouseleave: null
​
onmousemove: null
​
onmouseout: null
​
onmouseover: null
​
onmouseup: null
​
onmozfullscreenchange: null
​
onmozfullscreenerror: null
​
onpaste: null
​
onpause: null
​
onplay: null
​
onplaying: null
​
onpointercancel: null
​
onpointerdown: null
​
onpointerenter: null
​
onpointerleave: null
​
onpointermove: null
​
onpointerout: null
​
onpointerover: null
​
onpointerup: null
​
onprogress: null
​
onratechange: null
​
onreset: null
​
onresize: null
​
onscroll: null
​
onseeked: null
​
onseeking: null
​
onselect: null
​
onselectstart: null
​
onstalled: null
​
onsubmit: null
​
onsuspend: null
​
ontimeupdate: null
​
ontoggle: null
​
ontransitioncancel: null
​
ontransitionend: null
​
ontransitionrun: null
​
ontransitionstart: null
​
onvolumechange: null
​
onwaiting: null
​
onwebkitanimationend: null
​
onwebkitanimationiteration: null
​
onwebkitanimationstart: null
​
onwebkittransitionend: null
​
onwheel: null
​
outerHTML: "<div class=\"card-body\" id=\"cbody\">  \n            <div class=\"toolbar\" style=\"border:0px solid coral;\"></div>\n            <div id=\"calendar\" style=\"border:3px solid red;\" class=\"fc fc-media-screen fc-direction-ltr fc-theme-standard fc-liquid-hack\"><div class=\"fc-header-toolbar fc-toolbar fc-toolbar-ltr\"><div class=\"fc-toolbar-chunk\"><h2 class=\"fc-toolbar-title\">08.02.2021 – 04.04.2021</h2></div><div class=\"fc-toolbar-chunk\"><div class=\"fc-button-group\"><button class=\"fc-week-button fc-button fc-button-primary\" type=\"button\">Woche</button><button class=\"fc-month-button fc-button fc-button-primary fc-button-active\" type=\"button\">2 Monate</button></div></div><div class=\"fc-toolbar-chunk\"><button class=\"fc-cToday-button fc-button fc-button-primary\" type=\"button\">Heute</button><div class=\"fc-button-group\"><button class=\"fc-prevMonth-button fc-button fc-button-primary\" type=\"button\">&lt;&lt;</button><button class=\"fc-prevWeek-button fc-button fc-button-primary\" type=\"button\">&lt;</button><but…"
​
ownerDocument: HTMLDocument http://matpro/toolplan
​
parentElement: <div class="card" style="border:0px solid coral;padding-bottom:5px;">​
parentNode: <div class="card" style="border:0px solid coral;padding-bottom:5px;">​
part: DOMTokenList []
​
prefix: null
​
previousElementSibling: <div class="row" style="border:0px solid blue;">​
previousSibling: #text " 
          "
​
scrollHeight: 1201
​
scrollLeft: 0
​
scrollLeftMax: 0
​
scrollTop: 0
​
scrollTopMax: 0
​
scrollWidth: 1221
​
shadowRoot: null
​
slot: ""
​
spellcheck: false
​
style: CSS2Properties(0)
​
tabIndex: -1
​
tagName: "DIV"
​
textContent: "  \n            \n            08.02.2021 – 04.04.2021Woche2 MonateHeute<<<>>>Ressourcesort_by_alphaFebruar 2021März 2021April 2021678910111213Mo., 08.Di., 09.Mi., 10.Do., 11.Fr., 12.Sa., 13.So., 14.Mo., 15.Di., 16.Mi., 17.Do., 18.Fr., 19.Sa., 20.So., 21.Mo., 22.Di., 23.Mi., 24.Do., 25.Fr., 26.Sa., 27.So., 28.Mo., 01.Di., 02.Mi., 03.Do., 04.Fr., 05.Sa., 06.So., 07.Mo., 08.Di., 09.Mi., 10.Do., 11.Fr., 12.Sa., 13.So., 14.Mo., 15.Di., 16.Mi., 17.Do., 18.Fr., 19.Sa., 20.So., 21.Mo., 22.Di., 23.Mi., 24.Do., 25.Fr., 26.Sa., 27.So., 28.Mo., 29.Di., 30.Mi., 31.Do., 01.Fr., 02.Sa., 03.So., 04.Aimo-Clemens Leffers (0551) editAlex Rabe (0724) editAlfred Winter (0583) editAljoscha Raschke (0874) editAndre Elberling (0587) editAndre Michels (0714) editAndreas Milczewski (0575) editAnhänger (BRA-AW 429) editAnhänger (FRI-LA 103) editAnhänger (FRI-LA 51) editAnhänger (FRI-LA 80) editAstra (FRI-LA 144) editBaggeranhänger (FRI-LA 50) editBastian Müller (0510) editBenjamin Umbach (0578) editBennet Dreemann (0876) editBennet Visser (0911) editCaddy (BRA-SE 103) editCaddy (FRI-LA 20) editCorinna Wessels (0415) editDaniel Powollik (0593) editHeiko Wessels (0679) editMustermann (5559) editTestRessource (1234) editKarfreitagRosenmontagFastnachtAschermittwochPalmsonntagGründonnerstagOstersonntag\n          "
​
title: ""
​
<prototype>: HTMLDivElementPrototype { align: Getter & Setter, … }
```

so the `clientHeight` is obviously 1201. The Inspector of Firefox also gives me the correct info `div#cbody.card-body | 1223 x 1202.75 | Flex-Element`. However, the following code to get this height directly gives the wrong value 219. I can get the correct value for `clientWidth` though:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    let h = document.getElementById("cbody").clientHeight; 
    console.log(h);  // 219
    console.log(div.scrollHeight); // 219
    console.log(div.clientHeight); // 219
    console.log(div.offsetHeight); // 221
    console.log($('#cbody').height()); // 188.75

    let w = document.getElementById("cbody").clientWidth;
    console.log(w);  // 1221, works!
});
```

Here is the page:

```
<div class="content" style="padding-bottom:0px;">  
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="card" style="padding-bottom:5px;">              
          <div class="card-header card-header-danger card-header-icon">
            <div class="card-icon"><i class="material-icons">person</i></div>
            <h4 class="card-title">{{ __('Calendar') }}</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 text-right"></div>
          </div> 
          <div class="card-body" id="cbody">  
            <div class="toolbar"></div>
            <div id="calendar"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>          
    </div>      
  </div>
</div>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Your div with id cbody onlyu has two empty divs which have height 0 when empty. Are you setting the height with CSS?

Comment: What makes you think the divs are empty? They refer to the javascript plugin FullCalendar. You can see in my listing that the height is not 0.

Answer (score 0):

My intuition tells me this could be related to the lifecycle method where you're trying to access `DOM`.

Your event might be needed to be changed from `$(document).ready` to `$(window).load` for this to work. This is because the height of your `cbody` element seems to be controlled by the content of it's children which by default seem to be empty but later on (but before load) populated. The height you see while inspecting is the final one when the child elements contents are loaded.

The `ready` event is fired when the initial `DOM` structure is built i.e. the HTML is parsed.

The `load` event is fired later when all resources inclusive of images, styles and other resources are also loaded.

Another debugging try using [getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) :-

```
let cbody = document.querySelector("#cbody")
console.log(getComputedStyle(cbody).getPropertyValue('height'));
```

Comment: Your explanation makes total sense but using `$(window).on('load', function(){ ... });` just gave me the same wrong height of 219 (`$(window).load(function(){...});` is deprecated btw.).

Comment: I see. Can you try the other method I updated in the post ?

Comment: Although I still feel it's how your child elements are taking space and thus cbody's height. You might need to tweak the order of execution of code responsible for adding content to your cbody's child divs.

Comment: `.getPropertyValue('height')` gets me "220.75px". If `$(window).on('load', function(){` already executes after entire page load, what else could I do to tweak the order of execution? And I don't understand how `div = document.querySelector("#cbody");` can contain the correct `clientHeight` but won't let me get it.